# how to display data from console log to website react?

Tags: reactjs, post, button, console.log, history

In my code, I am able to show the available apartments with the post request. However, this can only be shown in the console.log. Yet I want to display it as a list on the website after pushing a Button. Subsequently, I want to achieve that the appearing webpage (after pushing the button) is going to display the list of the available apartments which is now displayed in the console log. However, I am confused about how I can achieve this with my current code.

```
function Search() {
    const history = useHistory();

    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());

    const [numberOfBeds, setNumberOfBeds] = useState();
 
    const selectionRange = {
      startDate: startDate,
      endDate: endDate,
      key: "selection"
    };

    const handleNumberOfBedsChange = (event) => setNumberOfBeds(event.target.value);

  
    function handleSelect(ranges) {
      setStartDate(ranges.selection.startDate);
      setEndDate(ranges.selection.endDate);
    }

    const onSearch = useCallback(() => {
      console.log("startDate: ", startDate);
      console.log("endDate: ", endDate);
      console.log("numberOfBeds", numberOfBeds);
   

      axios
        .post(`/availableapartments`, {
          startDate,
          endDate,
          numberOfBeds
        })
        .then((res) => {
         console.log(res);
         console.log(res.data);
       
         history.push('/availableapartments')

        }); 

    }, [startDate, endDate, numberOfBeds]);
  
 

    return (

      
      <div className="datepickersearch">
        <DateRangePicker ranges={[selectionRange]} onChange={handleSelect} />
  
        <h2> Number of guests</h2>
        <input min={0} defaultValue={2} max={7} type="number"  value={numberOfBeds}  onChange={handleNumberOfBedsChange}/>
        <Button onClick={onSearch}>Search Apartments</Button>
      
       
        
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Search;
```

Comment: You have to call the get method also, to display the data

Comment: I am pretty new to this but is it possible to request a get method without having a get mapping in the backend (I use Java as my backend) ?

Comment: not an issue, you have to use the GET method to display the data, in the react component.. post your put and get method API here

Comment: When I try to implement the GET method I am getting an error of 405. Do you maybe know how I can solve that problem?

Comment: that's from your backend issue try checking and let me know